# Location of upvote/downvote with pagination and share buttons

Tags: pagination, voting, footers, share

I have been working on a project in which users will be able to submit their articles.

Currently I have been testing on classic stories and here is a sample on [website](http://www.thestoryhut.com/personal/adventure-of-the-blue-carbuncle-3/).

[image]

Currently I have put demo upvote/downvote button in footer and pagination comes when user reaches the end of the page. I also need to include share button.

Should I put pagination, upvote/downvote, and share on the footer

Should I remove pagination and use infinite scroll? But in that case it will be difficult for users to reach on a page of a long article?

What should be right way for better user experience?

Comment: Do not add up / down buttons below pagibation. You can move your pagination bottom or right side and add up /down vote button between pagivation and artical.

Comment: @ShivamPandya : Can you show some example for that?

Comment: are you considering pagination for a single long article?

Comment: @MikeM : No , Actually I have hosted many full books too. In case of books it will become difficult to read without pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Users are comfortable with scrolling. Pagination for articles is often used in editorial sites for ad view opportunities. It does not reward the user to experience a broken narrative in a story for the sake of ad views.

Since you are not making money from advertising (that I can tell), it's a poor user experience even for long articles to have to jump to another page.

**Searching thru an article: a poor experience w/ pagination.**

Say you have an interesting article with a new concept or word. If I want to see all the instances of this word (and its surrounding content) I can use CMD + F to pull up a quick string search. How could I have continuity with pagination?

As for upvote / downvote buttons, one possibility is to put it to the right side of the header, and have a sticky header. Here's a quick cruddy sketch. I don't have any research as to if they would be better off on top, but a sticky header with infinite scroll would keep the buttons consistently visible.

You should also consider using an up / down bracket icon so users don't have to read the label to discern.

[image]

**A note on line length and readability**
The text you have right now is a bit small, with long line lengths.
You'll notice that most editorial sites use a minimum of 16 pixels for body text, often a bit bigger. Here's an older, but still relevant article:

**[16 Pixels Font Size: For Body Copy. Anything Less Is A Costly Mistake](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/16-pixels-body-copy-anything-less-costly-mistake/)**

Comment: Location for up-votes looks great to me. How do I handle it on mobile devices? I have changed font-size to 16. Thanks a lot for advice.

Comment: Perhaps for mobile you can reduce to the icons themselves to save room.

Comment: 20% content will  have more then 10 pages. Should I still go for infinite scrolling?

Comment: Since you're publishing a full book, you could use pagination for chapters perhaps. But long form articles w/ infinite scroll are pretty common. And each chapter page (for books) could have the section title 'Chapter One', etc. so users can see there's a unit of content that's consistently applied.

Comment: Will sure try that solution. Should I keep pagination stick on the footer then ?

Comment: That's worth a shot.

Answer (score 1):

As per my view, here are 3 possible options.

*Option 1*
[image]

*Option 2*

[image]

*Option 3*

[image]